# without select category not show subcategory

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

This is create.blade.php file. In this include css and js file too..
Html code and ajax code view file

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.codermen.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
 <script src="http://www.codermen.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{route('post.store')}}" >
       @csrf
       <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    Category<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                                    <option>select</option>
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                @endforeach
                            </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    Category<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-control">
                                    <option>select</option>
                        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
                <option value="{{$subcategory->id}}">{{$subcategory->subcategory}}</option>
                @endforeach
                            </select>
       </div>
</form>

@endsection
```

This is controller code which create function code of category and subcategory

```
public function create(Request $request){
    $categories = Category::all();
    $subcategories = DB::table('subcategories')
                        ->where('category_id', $request->category_id)
                        ->pluck('subcategory', 'id');
  return view('post.create', compact('categories', 'subcategories'));
}
```

This is route

```
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create')->name('post.create');
```

Problem is if i select category still no show related to subcategory
[image: Here show output]

[image: This is my category table]

[image: This is my subcategory table]

Comment: can you `console.log(res)`  after `if(res){`

Comment: I did it but not working -@SarojShrestha

Comment: do `console.log(res)` and show what it returns. You can check what is returning in res by hitting `ctrl+shift+i` and select console tab

Comment: This error occur Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . -@SarojShrestha

Comment: i put console.log in my code than show this error create:1 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952 -@SarojShrestha

Comment: Ok, it looks like I need to explain in little bit more detail. Why we are doing console.log? `console.log()` is not the medicine to fix your issue. We want to check what is returning in `res`. Maybe this data is in the different variable or some other thing. But, instead of showing what is returned in `res` it is showing some other error. This means you need to make sure is the ajax request is currently sending or not? If it is not sending any request how you supposed to receive data. So follow:  1) `console.log(res);` 2) if other errors arise. do `echo 'zz'; exit();` inside create function.

Comment: And check `ctrl+shift+i` network tab, then select xhr and say what is there in response tab.

Comment: error is same occur after i put the code in create function echo 'zz'; exit(); than return to page show zz and XHR tab show nothing -@SarojShrestha

Comment: Oh, I see you are sending both requests to the same create functions. That's, why it is showing `echo 'zz';` on the first request instead of in ajax. This means you need to create a different function in controller something like `getSubCategory()` and return JSON response from there and test again.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery append code looks like it is correct.  I think the problem may be in your routing.

You've got

```
url:"{{url('create')}}?category_id="+categoryID,
```

as a GET request called through the Laravel method `url()`.  It might help if you use `url()` here in the way you've got the route setup in web.php, which would use the full url path:

```
url:"{{url('post/create/')}}"+categoryID,
```

This lets the url() function add the parameter.  However, it might also help to account for the incoming parameter on your routes file if it is a GET request (and add $category_id to the controller method):

```
Route::get('post/create/{id}', 'PostController@create')
```

I would probably make a separate function just to get the subcategories - then make your ajax call to that function and just pull the subcategories.  A little cleaner.

But I think your problem may be in the routing and perhaps some of the above will help you.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to match it on your routes to the ajax (don't just copy exactly what I have), but I think if you can tweak it to get the page through and perhaps separate out to get just the subcategories, this may solve your problem.  I think the 'create' url may have been clashing or not going to the right place.  Just a guess - i don't know what else is in your routes file.

Comment: I still think this is an issue with your routing.  If you don't want to change via url(), you can try using the route() method like:   ----->     url: "{{route('post.create', ['category_id' => $category->id])}}"  I'm not sure how well this will work through ajax, but route() works with named routes.

Comment: Don't forget to allow for the parameter (id) on your Route::get() method in web.php -- otherwise you will get page not found.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide *what* doesn't work.  Creating a correct route, separating the function to get subcategories into its own function and then returning a JSON value *will* work - you just need to get the right data into res.

Answer (score 0):

you have done silly mistake , you are sending ajax request on change of category select dropdown to your create function , while your create function is rendering view post.create instead of return json response to ajax request .

so now what you can do ? 2 options available to you :

option 1 : create other function named "get_subcategory_by_category_id" and that will return subcategories in json , also create new route in routes/web.php for same .

option 2 : laravel provide `$request->ajax()` to detect that request is ajax or not ? so use that and return response in json , so you will get response .

```
public function create(Request $request){
    $categories = Category::all();
    $subcategories = DB::table('subcategories')
                        ->where('category_id', $request->category_id)
                        ->pluck('subcategory', 'id');

    if($request->ajax()){
        $response=array('categories'=>$categories,'subcategories'=>$subcategories);
        return response()->json($response,200);
    }
    return view('post.create', compact('categories', 'subcategories'));
}
```

your ajax function should be like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change','#category',function(){
    var categoryID = $(this).val();    
    if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
           type:"GET",
           url:"{{url('create')}}?category_id="+categoryID,
           dataType:'json',
           success:function(res){               
            if(res){
                console.log(res);
                // forloop through subcategory and append 
            }else{
               $("#subcategory").empty();
            }
           }
        });
    }else{
        $("#subcategory").empty();

    }      
   });
</script>
```

make sure that your request url is proper , also check Inspect Element > Network tab for ajax request response .

Comment: I applied your code but it doesn't show anything in element > Network tab

Comment: means that your ajax url is not proper , your ajax request is not working

Comment: try   `url:"{{route('post.create')}}?category_id="+categoryID`

Comment: or try simple `url:"/post/create?category_id="+categoryID`

Comment: @kinnariprajapati , please check updated script tag , you forgot to add your function inside document ready

Comment: @kinnariprajapati , either use `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change','#category',function(){.....});</script>`

Comment: @kinnariprajapati , or use `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#category').change(function(){ . ....  }); });</script>`

Comment: @kinnariprajapati , please reply it is working or not ?

Comment: I am confused in this so i was try api....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388615/api-have-decode-data-but-not-work-in-form