# Api have decode data but not work in form

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is my create.blade.php file which include ajax function API and HTML tag code..

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.codermen.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
    <script src="http://www.codermen.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{route('post.store')}}" >
                @csrf

<div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    Category<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                                    <option>select</option>
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                @endforeach
                            </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    Category<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="form-control">
                                    <option>select</option>
                        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
                <option value="{{$subcategory->id}}">{{$subcategory->subcategory}}</option>
                @endforeach
                            </select>
                </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       
                        $('#category').change(function(){
                var categoryID = $(this).val();
                if(categoryID){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url:"{{url('/api/getSubcategory/')}}/"+categoryID,

                        success:function(res){

                            if(res){
                                $("#subcategory").empty();
                                $("#subcategory").append('<option>Select</option>');
                                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                                    $("#category").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
                                });

                            }else{
                                $("#subcategory").empty();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $("#subcategory").empty();
                }
            });
</script>
@endsection
```

This is my controller code which include create function and getSubcategory function

```
public function create(){
    $categories = Category::all();
  $subcategories = Subcategory::all();
    return view('post.create', compact('categories', 'subcategories'));
}


 public function getSubcategory(Request $request){

    $id = $request->id;
    $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id',$id)->select
    ('Subcategory','id')->get();

      {{ dd(json_decode($subcategories, true)); }}
      // return view('post.create')->with('subcategories', json_decode($subcategories, true));

}
```

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::get('api/getSubcategory/{id}', 'PostController@getSubcategory' );
```

Now my problem is API have data and give me [image: API output]

but when i open this page and select category still not show related subcategory
[image: Error show this image]

Comment: This is different...In this i used API and learn to new how to call api in blade page -@Watercayman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id',$id)->select
('Subcategory','id')->get();
```

To

```
 $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id',$id)->select
('Subcategory','id')->pluck('subcategory', 'id');
```

Then

```
return json_encode($subcategories);
```

Possibly need to decode it in your ajax success function - try both.

Comment: Error in console and subcategory too..see this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"1":"all in cars","2":"maruti"}

Comment: You didn't decode it in your success function.  decode the res in your success function  res =  JSON.parse(res) and try again.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: In your ajax success function add: **res = JSON.parse(res)**  right under **if(res)** and it should now work.

Comment: yes its show but only 1 subcategory and console error is VM9600:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Hmm, then the non decoded should have worked.  Try this **res = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(res))** in the same place.  Also log res and see what it says (if this doesn't work)

Comment: Again same error like this and doesn't show subcategory Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"1":"all in cars","2":"maruti"}

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  The parse should have worked.  Try with a different variable?  **data = JSON.parse(res)**  and then use **data** in the each function instead of **res**.   If you want to further diagnose, you can even use eval, though this is not recommended:  **data = eval('(' + res + ')')** .  Then still use **data** instead of **res** in the each function

Comment: Thank you so much..its work..

Comment: How can I remove duplicate question?? can you help me?

Comment: Glad it worked.  You can just leave the question here.